# OnMapClickListener is lost when screen orientation changes

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

From what I know, when screen orientation changes, the whole activity is recreated again. I have GoogleMaps v2 and an OnMapClickListener, that is set in onCreate method and everything works perfectly until the screen orientation changes. However, onCreate and also onResume method run after the change of orientation, but the listener somehow gets lost...What am I missing? I also tried to force it and added the setter to both onCreate and onResume method..doesn´t really help.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

FontUtils.setCustomFont(this, (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView());
setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded()
{

if (mMap == null)
{
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
.getMap();
}
if (mMap != null)
{
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point)
{
if (options == null)
{
options = new MarkerOptions()
              .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
              .position(point)
              .title("Marker")
              .draggable(true)
              .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
              .fromResource(R.drawable.kruzok));
mMap.addMarker(options);
}
else
{
options.position(point);
mMap.clear();
    mMap.addMarker(options);
}
new GetTask().execute(point);
}
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:configChanges="orientation"`. It will not recreate the activity when screen orientation changed.

```
<activity android:name=".HomeMapView" android:label="@string/title_home" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

For Android 3.2 (API level 13) and newer:

```
<activity android:name=".HomeMapView" android:label="@string/title_home" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: This is not quite correct. Orientation isn't the only thing that changes when you rotate the device. [As of API 13](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) `screenSize` also needs to be added.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Only "orientation" did not help, but after adding "keyboardHidden" and "screenSize" it works perfectly!

Comment: Hey, and what if I want to handle changes of dialogFragments layout when screen orientaiton changes? it somehow does not go along..